# Uniform Convergence of $1/n\sin(n^​2 x)$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $f_n:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f_n(x)=1/n\sin(n​2 x)$. Does $f_n$ converge uniformly on $(0,1)$?

1/nsin(n squared x)

Can someone show me how this converges uniformly as I do not understand how to show it.

Comment: Yes, it converges uniformly to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $(f_n)$ is point-wise convergent to the zero function and we have

$$||f_n||_\infty\le\frac1n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$
so the convergence is uniform.

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\,,\,\,\forall\,x\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;|f_n'(x)|=|2\cos2n x|\le 2\implies \{f_n(x)\}$$

converges uniformly for any $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$